# Why I can't do a rest api request in Flutter

Tags: rest, flutter, dart, http-post

Can someone tell me why I'm getting the following exception, when I call my `POST` request:

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)
```

And it throws on this line:

```
var response = await http.post(url, body:data);
```

I have used breakpoint to check whether the data given is correct and it looks fine,

[image]

I'm stuck at this point for many hours and don't have any idea what to do next :/

REST api function:

```
addEvent(String title, startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime, description, city, address, entryType, int freePlacesCount) async {
    Map data = {
      "title":title,
      "startDate":startDate,
      "startTime":startTime,
      "endDate":endDate,
      "endTime":endTime,
      "description":description,
      "city":city,
      "address":address,
      "entryType":entryType,
      "freePlacesCount":freePlacesCount,
      //"organizer":organizer
    };

    var jsonResponse;
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/party';
    var response = await http.post(url, body:data);
```

Button:

```
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          addEvent(
            sharedPreferences.getString('eventName'),
            sharedPreferences.getString('dateFrom'),
            sharedPreferences.getString('timeFrom'),
            sharedPreferences.getString('dateTo'),
            sharedPreferences.getString('timeTo'),
            descriptionText.text,
            sharedPreferences.getString('eventCity'),
            sharedPreferences.getString('eventAddress'),
            sharedPreferences.getString('eventType'),
            sharedPreferences.getInt('freePlaces')
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: It is an error returned by your API ?

Comment: no, it's exception from flutter

Comment: @FPerroch i add screen from full exception

Comment: Is your API get called when you make your post ? From there I don't understand why you get that error.

Comment: yes///////////////////

Comment: Try to debug internal classes to understand what happens! this cast error generally come from a convert method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your body parameters. You can only set a `Map<String, String>` to the body parameter, in your case it's `Map<String, dynamic>`.

According to [http post](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) documentation:

> `body` sets the body of the request. It can be a `String`, a `List<int>` or
>   a `Map<String, String>`

For fixing it, convert your int type to String:

```
Map<String,String> data = {
   "title":title,
   "startDate":startDate,
   "startTime":startTime,
   "endDate":endDate,
   "endTime":endTime,
   "description":description,
   "city":city,
   "address":address,
   "entryType":entryType,
   "freePlacesCount":freePlacesCount.toString(),
};
```

Comment: i must provide ```freePlacesCount``` like a integer not a string

Comment: @Piotrek: As you can see that is not possible in the current set of supported body parameters. Did you tried the above code at-least ? Did your server failed when you post the above string data?

Comment: Yes, I try, return me Bad request from server

Comment: why I can't use ```Map<String, dynamic>```?

Comment: @Piotrek Check the documentation, it's designed in that way. You can ask the devs or post an issue on their github repo

Comment: I just change on backend to parse this string to int, thanks for help :)

Comment: @Piotrek: You are welcome. Just a note: You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/lib/src/request.dart